# Quitar las líneas entre elementos de un b-table de Bootstrap en modo stacked

Tags: bootstrap, vue.js

¿Es posible quitar las líneas entre elementos de un `b-table` de Bootstrap en modo stacked?

He intentado poniendo una clase al `b-table` con:

```
.custom-table tbody tr:not(:last-child) td {
  border-bottom: none !important; 
}
```

Pero no funciona. ¿Alguna idea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por las aportaciones, pero estoy intentando con la solución de @Marcos y no me funciona...estoy probando en un archivo .js donde creo los fields del b-table y ahí consigo quitarlos...pero solo los quiero quitar para el modo stacked y en pantalla grande que se vean como siempre. Solo consigo quitarlos para pantalla pequeña(modo stacked lo tengo para pantalla pequeña), pero luego mostrarlos en pantalla grande imposible... Esta es lo del archivo .js: (en la última columna me quita bordes, pero para todos los tamaños :( )

const tableColumns = [ { key: "file_name", label: "Firma", sortable: true, class:"pl-sm-3",tdClass:" pl-sm-3 pl-0" }, { key: "date_creation", label: "Última actualización", sortable: true,}, { key: "state", label: "Estado", sortable: true }, { key: "players", label: "Firmantes", sortable: true, tdClass: "text-md-center text-left " }, { key: "actions", label: "Acciones", thClass: "text-right",class:"pr-md-3 pr-0 border-white border-sm-secondary", }]

Comment: Debes colocar un [MRE] y explicar mejor el resultado esperado que al menos yo no he entendido que buscas

Comment: @Yussef cuando bs pasa la grilla a stacked en modo sm o algun otro, entonces pone lineas entre las columnas (que ahora son filas).. la pregunta esta bien formulada, algun genio en css seguro sabe como sacarlas....

Comment: Prueba con `.b-table.stacked tbody tr:not(:last-child) td { ... }`, si no funciona sería necesario que adjuntes algún código HTML para poderlo reproducir.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías lograrlo así:

- Creamos una nueva regla, supongamos `.b-table-border-none` e indicamos:

  ```css
  .table.b-table-border-none td,
  .table.b-table-border-none th {
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
  }
  ```
- Cuando agregamos el `<b-table>` agreamos `class="b-table-border-none"`

#### Ejemplo:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app'
  })
}
```

```css
.table.b-table-border-none td,
.table.b-table-border-none th {
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-table stacked hover class="b-table-border-none" caption-top label="Table Options" 
    :items="[
      { age: 40, name: 'admin1', email: 'hoge@for.jp' },
      { age: 21, name: 'admin2', email: 'huga@for.jp' },
      { age: 89, name: 'admin3', email: 'piyo@for.jp' },
      { age: 38, name: 'admin4', email: 'aaaaa@for.jp' }
    ]"
    :fields="[
      { key: 'name', label: 'Name' },
      { key: 'email', label: 'Email'}
    ]">
  </b-table>
</div>
```